# How to create an api 19 app in android studio 2

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I have programmed an app that uses appcompatv7:23 then my app doesnt work on android devices with api lower than 23, i would like to program the same app to be used on >= 19 < 23.

I have created a new project in android studio but i always  get compilesdkversion 23, then when i change it to 19 i get  a lot of errors on gradle.

How could i create a new project that be compiled on api level 19?

Every new project on android studio add automaticlly appcompatv7:23 then not run in 19,20,21 nor 22 api level devices.

Comment: Did you set the `minSdkVersion` in your project's `build.gradle`?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need to download some tools from the Android SDK Manager.
You can find it here (red):

[image]

Click on `Launch Standalone SDK Manager` and check if you have installed the right build tools for your project.
You can also edit your question and add the errors. This can help a lot to find a quick solution!

Comment: yes i did it minsdk and download every one api i need, i think is something with google play services, my app works but gmaps doesnt show points correcly, in fact, not even move and show the entire world map